# Regular Expression in Apache-Alias not working

Tags: regex, apache, alias

Why does

```
AliasMatch .*\.(png|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|js|css|woff|ttf|svg)$ /my-location/
```

+

```
GET /pages/index/index.js HTTP/1.1
```

=

```
[30/Jul/2014:12:55:28 -0700] "GET /pages/index/index.js HTTP/1.1" 404 433 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36"
```

?

Comment: The expected outcome is `/my-location/` instead of `http://localhost/`?

Comment: Actually /my-location/ should be a location on the local file system.

Comment: Has `/my-location/` been mapped to `localhost` in the `hosts` file? Could you change `/my-location/` to something else e.g. `/helloapache`, which should result into `/helloapache` if navigated to `/pages/index/index.js`

Comment: `/my-location/` does appear nowhere in the `hosts` file. But I don't quite get why it should - can you elaborate on that? AFAIK the directive `AliasMatch` does redirect requests to the local file system an /my-location/ is simply a respective path on that file system.

Comment: I will do a test on my system. Which version of Apache2 are you using?

Comment: Wow that would be marvellous! It's `Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58392/discussion-between-user2820379-and-utrecht).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was

```
AliasMatch (.*\.(png|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|js|css|woff|ttf|svg))$ /my-location/$1
```

The reason for that is:`"[...]  Alias will automatically copy any additional part of the URI, past the part that matched, onto the end of the file path on the right side, while AliasMatch will not. This means that in almost all cases, you will want the regular expression to match the entire request URI from beginning to end, and to use substitution on the right side."` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch)